# how backbone requirejs works for my case?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, lazy-loading, js-amd

I am building an application using requirejs and backbone, I would like to load modules asynchronously after some actions.

say I have some modules like

```
authentication
module1
module2
module3
module4
platform
utils
```

Initially I need to load authentication module and after success

I would like to load particular module(views, models,collections) based on route using requirejs.

how can I load modules as explained?

Please suggest, if there is any boilerplate available for this pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you using marionette module:

In module you can use

```
startWithParent = false
```

And then start the module in the desired route

For example you have routes defined as

```
appRoutes: {
        'login': 'login'
}
```

In the controller

```
login: function(){
       // you can require the login module here
      // if you using backbone only you can require views, models, collections in the       
      //similar way in the desired routes
      require(['modules/LoginModule'], function(LoginModule) {
            App.module('LoginModule').start();
      });
}
```

When you want to stop the module

```
 App.module('LoginModule').stop();
```

Comment: first of all thanks for reply with solution, what if user directly went to module url without login, I know it feel like simple but I would like to know your version and the best way to do it! thank you

Comment: I would like to know, is there any boilerplate or example for this kind of application?

Comment: @Susan I am not sure of any boilerplate but here's codebase of David Sulc Marionette book https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction. All modules are in a way sub app so there's header app, about app, contact app. Its one of the nice ways to achieve modular structure. I am not sure if it suits your desire but it certainly is interesting to go through.

Comment: the link is not useful its just introduction to  Marionette application.

Comment: Maybe an article then https://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/philip-kedy/modularizing-your-backbone-router-using-requirejs. Ofcourse these are just hints and suggestion rather than full fledged boiler plat application. If not satisfied, try looking for keyword Organizing backbone modular approach

Comment: that is really awesome dude, Thank you very much for spending time